# Vertical Upright Text in CSS vs Google Sheets

Tags: html, css, google-sheets, text

As an experiment, I thought it would be fun duplicating a small Google Sheet when I ran into an issue with Vertical Upright text in CSS and how it displayed differently across browsers. I noticed though, that in Google Sheets, each browser displayed the Vertical Text the same way. My Question is, what CSS is Google Sheets using that I may be missing?

[Here's an image with the Vertical Text in Google Sheets (left samples) in Chrome, Safari, Firefox & Edge, respectively VS in CSS (right samples)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9ceJ.png)

[Here's a link to the Google Sheet with Vertical Text spanning 30 rows in one column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12EIRd1aEABjrX-Nk-hRSJGIVK5sCsnt_BDvOFbSBOXk/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's the CSS for a DIV with class "vertical" I'm using:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 30px;
height: 630px;
padding: 0 0 0 7px;

writing-mode: vertical-lr;
text-orientation: upright;

font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
font-weight: bold;
color: #ffffff;

background-color: #434343;
```

The HTML & BODY have zero margin & padding.

Any insight would be helpful. Thank you.